# Accessing cells with superscripts from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to access value stored in cell which has superscript(like ft²). How ever VBA is returning ft2 when I print it in a message box. Can any body tell me how to access actual value in the cell from VBA?

Comment: Superscript is just formatting within the cell, and not a part of the cell's value.  It might help to explain in a little more detail exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to generate a JSON string from the values in cell and POST it to a web service. Most of my values have unit with superscripts. I am not able to find a solution for sending the values as it is in the cell to my web service.

Comment: You have to loop though the characters and check whether it is superscript or not....

Comment: How are you going to represent superscript in JSON?

Comment: It may work to identify known text strings with superscripts and output the formatting properly when you encounter them.

Comment: Are you looking for the ⁿ character codes?  You'll have to pass them as Unicode values into your JSON file.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro - ¹, ² and ³ are ASCII codes (185, 178 and 179). Anything higher than that (and ⁰) usually uses the UniChars starting at U+2070 (&8304).

Comment: @Jeeped, that's why I said Unicode in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to locate cells containing superscript characters:

```
Sub FindingSupers()
   msg = "The following cells contain superscript characters" & vbCrLf

   For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      If r.Value <> "" Then
         For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
            If r.Characters(i, 1).Font.Superscript Then
              msg = msg & r.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf
              Exit For
            End If
         Next i
      End If
   Next r
   MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: Answers the OP's question wonderfully, however, not sure the OP knows what they are asking.  Up vote for helping future Googler's.